# How to repeat alphabet Ceaser Cipher

Tags: python, encryption

I saw someone's Ceaser cipher problem and tried to write my own. I got everything done except for the fact that my alphabet needs to wrap around

```
#User input
user_message = input("Input the text you would like encrypted (no 
characters)")

#Cipher function
def Ciphertext(message):
     cipher = ""
     for i in message:
#takes each letter in message
        number_code = ord(i) + 3
        letter_code = chr(number_code)
    cipher = cipher + letter_code
return cipher

#Unencrypted function
def Plaintext(cipher):
     text = ""
     #loops to get each number
     for i in cipher:
     #takes each letter in cipher
         unencrypted_code = ord(i) - 3
         unencrypted_letter_code = chr(unencrypted_code)
         text =  text + unencrypted_letter_code
    print(text)
#Prints
print("Encrypted message")
print(Ciphertext(user_message))
print("Unencrypted message")
Plaintext(Ciphertext(user_message))
```

Ok so I changed my code to this:
    #User input
    user_message = input("Input the text you would like encrypted (no 
    characters)")

```
#Cipher function
def Ciphertext(message):
    cipher = ""
    for i in message:
    #takes each letter in message then coverts it to number subtracts the 
diffrence then converts it back into characters
        number_code = ord(i) + 3
        letter_code = chr(number_code)
        if number_code >= ord("z"):
            number_code = number_code - 123
            number_code = number_code + ord("a")
            letter_code = chr(number_code)
        cipher = cipher + letter_code
    return cipher

cipher = Ciphertext(user_message)

#Unencrypted function
def Plaintext():
    text = ""
    #loops to get each number
    for i in cipher:
    #takes each letter in cipher
        unencrypted_code = ord(i) - 3
        if unencrypted_code >= ord("z"):
            unencryted_code = unencrypted_code + 26
        unencrypted_letter_code = chr(unencrypted_code)
        text =  text + unencrypted_letter_code
    print(text)
#Prints
print("Encrypted message")
print(Ciphertext(user_message))
print("Unencrypted message")
Plaintext()
```

But it continues to run this:^_` when it type in xyz

Comment: By repeat, do you mean, for example, 'z' needs to wrap around to 'c'?

Comment: I do mean that.

Comment: Check if ```number_code > ord('z')```. If it is, then take the difference and add it on to ```ord('a')```

Comment: `cipher = cipher + letter_code` needs to be indented another level so it's inside the loop.

Comment: If `number_code > ord('z')`, subtract 26 from it.

Comment: And if `unencrypted_code < 0`, add 26 to it.

Comment: @Learningcoding13 Do you mean like hours on a [clock](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulo operator % returns the remainder of the division of two numbers, essentially "wrapping around" a value.

You can use this behavior to wrap your cipher around. Note that if you're using `ord()`, you'll be given the ASCII representation of a number - note that this is different for uppercase and lowercase letters. For example, 'A' is 65, and 'a' is 97. If you plan for your cipher to preserve the case of your letters, you'll need to subtract 65 and 97, depending on case, to properly use modulo. Try something like this:

```py
def Ciphertext(message):
    cipher = ""
    for i in message:
        #determine if this is an uppercase or lowercase character, and treat it accordingly
        number_code = 0
        if i.isupper():
            number_code = (((ord(i) - 65) + 3) % 26) + 65
        elif i.islower():
            number_code = (((ord(i) - 97) + 3) % 26) + 97
        else:
            number_code = ord(i)
        letter_code = chr(number_code)
        cipher += letter_code
    return cipher

def Plaintext(cipher):
    text = ""
    for i in cipher:
        unencrypted_code = 0
        if i.isupper():
            unencrypted_code = (((ord(i) - 65) - 3) % 26) + 65
        elif i.islower():
            unencrypted_code = (((ord(i) - 97) - 3) % 26) + 97
        else:
            unencrypted_code = ord(i)
        letter_code = chr(unencrypted_code)
        text += letter_code
    return text

print (Ciphertext("Hello world! wxyz"))
print (Plaintext("Khoor zruog! zabc"))
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/CourageousSilentPlane)